# WCF POST CORS - Location header changed

Tags: azure, wcf, post, iis, cors

I've hosted to IIS in Azure a WCF. I need to do a post CORS client side (I'm using dojo js).

I expect this scenario
POST REQUEST -> OPTIONS PRE-FLIGHT -> POST RESPONSE

but if I see the chrome dev tools network I get:
POST Request -> OPTIONS PRE-FLIGHT -> AUTOMATICALLY GET REQUEST -> METHOD NOT ALLOWED (my WCF method only accept POST method)

There also a strange thing, if i see the GET response, it has status code 302 found and in the response header LOCATION : /rest/**(X(1)S(xnrhdgei0ecua5s550yxqiv1))**/login/ but I don't know what **(X(1)S(xnrhdgei0ecua5s550yxqiv1))** is.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: This article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) help me to undestand the problem. I solved adding <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false"/> into the web.config

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false"/>` into the web.config. See my previous comment for additional details